# Django 1.8 run on windows server 2008

Tags: django, windows, python-2.7, windows-server-2008

I have a question about run django project in production on my windows server 2008. I tried to run it with apache but I can't get the mod_wsgi.so file for my apache server. 
Is is possible to do it with cherrypy or can i get some advice for an other solution or get the correct mod_wsgi.so file to run my apache server with this module.

Thanks in advance